# Circlet of Persuasion an ODD boost that begs for explanation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, boosts

So in this question [Can I create +1 stat boosting item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16688/can-i-create-a-1-stat-boosting-item/108784?noredirect=1#comment262305_108784) we see it suggested the game shouldn't have items that give odd numbered boosts. What's with items like Circlet of Persuasion which do exactly that? Aren't they breaking that same rule/advice?"

Answer (score 7):

Nope. The question you linked specifically speaks of odd-numbered boosts to attributes (strength, dexterity etc). These bonuses will have a varying benefit for the player depending on their unmodified attribute: because of how attribute modifiers are calculated, a character with an odd dexterity score would benefit a lot from a +1 dexterity item, but a character with an even dexterity score wouldn't as their modifier would remain unchanged. Therefore you'd have a magic item that only works for some people and not others, with no real in-universe justification.

The circlet, on the other hand, doesn't affect one's attributes, it just gives a direct bonus to rolls. It works equally well for anyone using it without weird mechanical kinks.